# How can I ensure a bind is updated on the VM before a component's props get populated

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

So I've a data property that is populated from a field on my vm

```
var vm = new Vue{
    data: {
        somevalue: null,
    },
}
```

This value is bound to a field that is prepopulated on load:

```
<input v-model:somevalue="1" />
```

I then use this value and pass it to a component as a prop. In that component, I have a function which gets called once, that uses this value.

```
<some-component v-bind:propofsomevalue="somevalue"></some-component>

...
//the innards of the component
prop: ["propofsomevalue"]
ready: function(){
     //Does something with this.propofsomevalue
}
```

The problem is on ready/compile/attached etc, the base vm.somevalue hasn't yet updated, and so the prop doesn't get updated until later on down the lifecycle. So whenever it runs propofsomevalue is null. How can I perform this function once the props have been inserted.

It works if I directly pass a value, instead of using the bind.

```
<some-component v-bind:propofsomevalue="1"></some-component>
```

It works, but the problem is that this value isn't static and gets populated dynamically by asp server side.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not set the initial property in the Vue instance and not in the UI?  From a "separation of concerns" standpoint, it doesn't feel right to initialize data via the UI.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response: I don't have access to the JS file from where I'm compiling the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just put a "watch" on the prop and perform the action once the value has changed to something other than null?